# Re-engineering of two classes to avoid code duplication

Tags: java, optimization, design-patterns

I was asked to re-engineering these two Java classes in order to avoid code duplication and improve maintainability.

```
public class Adder {
  public int sum(int[] array) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      result += array[i];
    }
  return result;
}

public class Multiplier {
  public int multiply(int[] array) {
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      result *= array[i];
    }
  return result;
}
```

The different `result` initializations are my main problem.

Comment: Why not pass the initial value as a parameter in one common method?

Comment: There are two different operations. I don't think there is much duplication here. I'd keep it as it is. Btw, Adder and Multiplier sound artificial a little bit for me. Why not create Calculator class with sum and multiply method?

Comment: I think that the actual operation needs to be isolated from the for cycle, but `result` is not in the same scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I`d like to post my answer in spite of the question already having a good answer(I was too slow).
The point in my solution is that is open for new Operations, you don't have to know different function names(so you can i.e. inject ArrayFunction into other classes):

```
public abstract class ArrayFuntion {

    public int compute(int[] array) {
        int result = initResult();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            result = compute(result, array[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected abstract int compute(int result, int i);

    protected abstract int initResult();

}


public class Adder extends ArrayFuntion{

    @Override
    protected int compute(int result, int arrayItem) {
        return result + arrayItem;
    }

    @Override
    protected int initResult() {
        return 0;
    }

}


public class Multiplier extends ArrayFuntion {

    @Override
    protected int compute(int result, int arrayItem) {
        return result * arrayItem;
    }

    @Override
    protected int initResult() {
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well done. With an interface on top it would be even nicer.

Answer (score 2):

If you really think this requires some refactoring consider this:

```
public class Calculator {
    public int multiply(int[] array) {
        return calculate(1, array, (a, b) -> a * b);
    }

    public int sum(int[] array) {
        return calculate(0, array, (a, b) -> a + b);
    }

    public int calculate(int initValue, int[] array, IntBinaryOperator operator) {
        return Arrays.stream(array).reduce(initValue, operator);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        System.out.println(calculator.multiply(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}));
        System.out.println(calculator.sum(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}));
    }
}
```

Comment: Very strong and concise, but imho it puts too much power in programmer hands and less in those of designer.

Comment: I think sometimes it's not worth creating complex abstraction for simple problems

Answer (score 2):

Here is my proposal. it takes the iteration as common code specified in super abstract class. the initial value and math operation are delegated to concrete implementations

```
public abstract class CommonMath {
    public int calculate(int initialValue, int[] array) {
        int result = initialValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            result = mathOperation(result, array[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public abstract int mathOperation(int result, int arrayItem);
}

public class Adder extends CommonMath {
    public int sum(int[] array) {
        return calculate(0, array);
    }

    @Override
    public int mathOperation(int result, int arrayItem) {
        return result + arrayItem;
    }
}

public class Multiplier extends CommonMath {
    public int multiply(int[] array) {
        return calculate(1, array);
    }

    @Override
    public int mathOperation(int result, int arrayItem) {
        return result * arrayItem;
    }
}

// test
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        int[] array; {
            array = new int[3];
            array[0] = 1;
            array[1] = 2;
            array[2] = 4;
        }
        System.out.println("sum " + Arrays.toString(array) + " " + new Adder().sum(array));
        System.out.println("multi " + Arrays.toString(array) + " " + new Multiplier().multiply(array));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output

```
sum [1, 2, 4] 7
multi [1, 2, 4] 8
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
public abstract class Calculator {
   protected int aggregate(int[] array, int startValue) {
       int result = startValue;
       for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          result = this.aggregateSingle(array[i], result);
       }
       return result;
    }

    protected abstract int aggregateSingle(int nextValue, int oldAggregation);
}

public class Adder extends Calculator {
   public int sum(int[] array) {
      return this.aggregate(array, 0);
   }
   protected int aggregateSingle(int nextValue, int oldAggregation) {
      return nextValue + oldAggregation;
   }
}

public class Multiplier extends Calculator {
   public int multiply(int[] array) {
      return this.aggregate(array, 1);
   }
   protected int aggregateSingle(int nextValue, int oldAggregation) {
      return nextValue * oldAggregation;
   }
}
```

This approach even keeps the class structure, which could be important in case that the classes `Adder` and `Multiplier` are being used externally (they are `public`!)

Personally, I don't consider this entire activity to be an "improvement to maintainability" as such: It's more LoC and even more complex due to this nature of inheritence. The question to me feels like some theoretical question, which should educate your mind towards how refactoring should be done - but exactly misses the most important point: Keep simple things simple - even if they may be a bit redundant.

Comment: I'm agree with you. And yes, it's an exercise to learn how to think even if the solution seems useless.